# Problems with AngularJS $location.path

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I am having fun and games with a troublesome AngularJS route, so lets see if I can explain this as well as I can.

APP.JS:

```
app = angular.module("index", []);

app.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/booking/damage/:regnumber', {
                templateUrl: 'damage',
                controller: 'DamageCtrl'
        }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
        });
    }
]);

app.controller('IndexCtrl', function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.regnumber = '';
    $scope.progress = function() {
        if ($scope.regnumber !== '') {  
            $location.path('/booking#/damage/' + $scope.regnumber);
        } else {
            $location.path('/booking#/damage');
        }
    };
});
```

My initial page has a path of

`http://localhost/windscreens/glass/index#/index`

and within this page is a form that via `ng-submit="progress()` calls the $scope.progress function within my IndexCtrl controller. There is a field in the form of ng-model="regnumber".

So when filling in the input field with lets say "ABC" and clicking on the button, I'd expect the path to become:

```
http://localhost/windscreens/glass/booking#/damage/ABC
```

But it becomes

`http://localhost/windscreens/glass/index#/booking%23/damage/ABC`

Thing is I am still really becoming used to the Angular routing system and haven't quite got it yet. Any advice on this will be appreciated!

Why am I seeing what I am seeing? What have I got wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Angular $routeProvider can only change the part of the URL after the hash (`#`), so when calling `$location.path()`, you just use a plain URL fragment like you defined in the route for `DamageCtrl`.

#### Some explanation

I'm going to simplify a bit here, but hopefully it will help you understand what's going on.

You're making a SPA (single-page app), so the URL you enter in your browser to get into your app doesn't change while you navigate between routes; by default $routingProvider appends `#/whatever/route` to that base URL. In your case it looks like you have your entry point (`ng-app`) in a file called `/windscreens/glass/index`, so all routes will get appended to that.

Because you don't have an `/index` route defined that we can see, I'm not sure how `http://localhost/windscreens/glass/index#/index` is working for you. It should send you to `http://localhost/windscreens/glass/index#/` because your `otherwise` route is just `/`.

#### Back to the question

If I understand your question correctly, I would make the index file (where `ng-app` lives) `/windscreens/glass/index.html`, then you can just enter `http://localhost/windscreens/glass/` to get into the app, because the webserver will serve the contents of index.html by default.

At that point, your index page URL would become `http://localhost/windscreens/glass/#/`, and your `/booking/damage/` routes would be `http://localhost/windscreens/glass/#/booking/damage/ABC` etc. The code to navigate to them would then be

```
$location.path('/booking/damage');
```

Answer (score 2):

Angular routing changes the route on the page; it doesn't take you to a new directory or page.

So if index.html contains your Angular app and you have routes for "booking", "reservation", "cancellations", etc.  You'll end up with urls that look like:

```
/glass/index.html#/booking
/glass/index.html#/reservation
/glass/index.html#/cancellations
```

The route merely appends itself to the index.html.

So, in a sense, your routes are working correctly. The `%23` that you see being added is the url encoded `#` sign.

If you have a second Angular app that is found at `/glass/booking` and you're trying to forward the user to it, you can use `$window.location.hash` and `$window.location.pathname`.  For example,

```
$window.location.hash = "/damage/ABC";
$window.location.pathname = "/windscreens/glass/booking";
should take you to:
/windscreens/glass/booking#/damage/ABC
```

Comment: Both answers by yourself (@gwmccull) and @mike partridge were very helpful. I did later realise having read my books again that this was the case. Single page apps after all!